# Launching an application on a dedicated core

Tags: python, multicore

I have a large amount of simulation files.

These are to be executed and run in a specific software. I know I can use python to instruct my software to run one specific file.

I would like to know if I can use python force my computer to dedicate one core per simulation.

For instance, let's say that I have 10 simulations to run and 3 cores. I want something like that

- Run Simulation1 on core 1 only
- Run Simulation2 on core 2 only
- Run Simulation3 on core 3 only

-- wait one of the simulation to be finished --

...

-- Simulation 2 finished --

- Run Simulation4 on core 2 only

etc.

In essence, I sort of want python to instruct my OS to associate a specific core to a task.
Do you know if something is possible?

Thanks a lot

E

Answer (score 0):

From the python3.8 docs:

> os.sched_setaffinity(pid, mask)
>   Restrict the process with PID pid (or the current process if zero) to a set of CPUs. mask is an iterable of integers representing the set of CPUs to which the process should be restricted.

In the end though the OS's scheduler will make an executive decision on where each process goes.